# Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code ]])

Tags: php

Have been staring to this exception for while and have no clue whats going wrong.

> Fatal Error: Wrong parameters for `Exception([string $exception [, long $code ]])`

It seems pretty straight forward, the Exception expects a message and a optional code, though for some reason the code won't agree with me. Even when I drop the last parameter `$e` (for keeping the stacktrace), this same error pops up.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception('Client cannot be created', 0, $e);
}
```

Only when i omit both the code (`0`) and the previous exception (`$e`), the error is thrown correctly.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception('Client cannot be created');
}
```

Comment: @diEcho $this->service = new SoapClient(VHS_WSDL, array("trace" => 1));

Comment: Currious thing though, the PHP documention http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php is talking about the code as being a int, though, the exception is talking about a long.

Comment: have a look at the doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Which PHP version? Can you supply code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: i think you must read :http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.use-soap-error-handler.php . Also under example  i have seen  only single argumented `Exception()`

Comment: http://in.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php : see examples,there is also called a single argument `Exception()`

Comment: The current version is 5.2.7. I found that supplying the previous exception is supported from 5.3. So I hat to delete that argument anyway, and the code wasn't really used by my code so stripped it to the working exception. Though, don't have an anwser why teh code with the $code paramater does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Although i never worked with SOAP technology, so just taken from   [`SoapClient manual`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

> The exceptions option is a boolean value defining whether soap errors
>   throw exceptions of type [`SoapFault`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/soapfault.soapfault.php)

and **soapFault** syntax is

```
SoapFault::SoapFault ( string $faultcode , 
                       string $faultstring [, 
                       string $faultactor [, 
                       string $detail [, 
                       string $faultname [, 
                       string $headerfault ]]]] );
```

so I will suggest you to check all the examples on manual. here i got one exmaple

**To get custom Soap Error Codes use in the catch `$e->faultcode` instead of `$e->getCode`.**

```
<?php 
try { 
    // ... 
} catch (SoapFault $e) { 
    echo $e->faultcode; 
} 
?>
```

one more example:

```
try { 
            $options = array( 
                'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 
                'exceptions'=>true, 
                'trace'=>1, 
                'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE 
            ); 
            $client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/end_point.wsdl', $options); 

        } catch (Exception $e) { 
            echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>"; 
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }
```

Hope it helps.